# How to find the number of operations in a nested loop with dependent variable?

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-science, analysis

I am having difficulty trying to find the total number of operations in the following code block:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i *= 2) {
   for(int j = 1; j <= i; j *= 2) {
       // What is the number of operations here, with respect to n?
   }
}
```

My thinking was that:
there are floor(log_2(n)) operations in the outer loop, and log_2(i) operations in the inner loop. I am not sure if my thinking is right, and how I would go from here... How could this be written in terms of solely n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, there are `floor(log_2(n))` operations in the outer loop. For simplicity let's say `log_2(n)` operations. It won't matter so much for the large number of inputs. In the inner loop, number of operations will be `log_2(i)` for each case.  
So, from `i`=1 to `i`=n, number of inner loop operations:

```
A = log_2(1)+1 (i = 1) + log_2(2)+1 (i = 2) + log_2(4)+1 (i = 4) + ... + log_2(n)+1 (i = n)
A =  1 + 2 + 3 + ... log_2(n) + 1
A = (log_2(n) + 2) * (log_2(n)+1) / 2 
A = ((log_2(n))^2 + 3*log_2(n) + 2)/2
```

Total number of operations = `(log(n)^2 + 3log(n) + 2)/2` 
In short, time complexity of the algorithm will be : `O(log(n)^2)`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I can see that O(nlogn) is a valid upper bound, but technically isn't the exact bound Θ((log_2(n))^2)?

Comment: I would say exact bound is ```Θ(log_2(n!))``` rather than ```Θ((log_2(n))^2)```. Did you mean to say ```Θ(log_2(n!))```? If not, could you explain your reasoning?

Comment: Yup. The outer loop goes from 2^0, 2^1, ..., 2^k ≤ n -> log_2(n) operations. When i = 2^0, j = 2^0; when i = 2^1, j = 2^0, 2^1; when i = 2^2, j = 2^0, 2^1, 2^2; in general, when i = 2^k, j = 2^0, 2^1, ..., 2^k. From this, I noticed the total number of operationss was the summation, T(n) = (1 + 2, + 3 + ... + log_2(n)) = (log_2(n) * log_2(n)+1)/2. I verified this in the code by incrementing a counter variable in the inner loop and it seems to be correct.

Comment: And then (log_2(n) * log_2(n) + 1)/2 is roughly (log_2(n))^2, making the exact bound (log_2(n))^2

Comment: I just realized I actually made a small error... The summation actually goes up to log_2(n) + 1, hence the number of operations is (log_2(n) + 1)(log_2(n) + 2)/2

Comment: Yes, you are right. Time complexity will be ```O(log(n)^2)```. I had a mistake in my calculation, now fixed it.